# How does the host name resolution of anyname.localhost resolves to IPv6 ::1 address?

Tags: linux, networking, tcp, dns

In an Ubuntu 20 or 22 LTS, if I attempt to use a hostname like `anyname.localhost` it always seems to resolve to IPv6 ::1 address.

In an old RHEL 6, if I attempt to use a hostname like `anyname.localhost` it always seems to resolve to IPv4 127.0.0.1 address.

In a MS-Windows or MacOS 12.6 machine, this does not seem to happen. (It only happens if I manually edit /etc/hosts and manually add an host alias to 127.0.0.1

`127.0.0.1     localhost localhost.localdomain somename.localhost`

)

Is this `any.sequence.of.names.localhost` resolution to `::1` (localhost) always garanteed to happen ? By what reason ? In what Linux distros ?

I have a few projects where it seems useful to have many localhost aliases without having to edit `/etc/hosts`, but I searched about TCP and DNS quirks, and found nothing about this behaviour. (Not very sure what I should search for). Not sure if I can depend on this behaviour.

Comment: PS: I did find RFC2606 , but it doesn't explain it either.

Comment: The behavior is initially determined by the hosts line in `/etc/nsswitch.conf`

Comment: /etc/nsswitch.conf only specifies the list of providers for DNS resolution.
Does not explains who defined that one of this providers (what provider?) should resolve any.sequence.of.names.ending.in.localhost to ::1 ?

Comment: This should answer your question (which BTW is offtopic here as not related to programming): https://serverfault.com/a/1065514/396475

Comment: Thanks for your pointer, but I get even more confused.
On Ubuntu 22, my nsswitch has

hosts:          files mdns4_minimal [NOTFOUND=return] dns

(So, it should always stop at NOTFOUND. But it resolves to ::1).

Sure it is not a "programming language" question, but I am setting up a reverse http docker proxy, using traefik, and I really don't understand where does this behaviour comes from. (Windows and Mac do not seem to support it, at least).

Comment: Does the „old RHEL 6” host actually have an IPv6 address?

Comment: No. It should have ::1 but ping ::1 gives ping: unknown host ::1
. Maybe the RHEL 6 has IPv6 disabled.
$ sysctl -a 2>/dev/null | grep disable_ipv6
net.ipv6.conf.all.disable_ipv6 = 0
net.ipv6.conf.default.disable_ipv6 = 0
net.ipv6.conf.eth0.disable_ipv6 = 0
net.ipv6.conf.lo.disable_ipv6 = 0
net.ipv6.conf.virbr0.disable_ipv6 = 1
net.ipv6.conf.virbr0-nic.disable_ipv6 = 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, thanks to the link posted in the comments above by Patrick Mevzek, I could reach a documented explanation.

For the Ubuntu 20/22 LTS, it seems to use systemd-resolved for DNS resolution.
And, as it says on
https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd-resolved.service.html

> Synthetic Records
>
> ...
>
> The hostnames "localhost" and "localhost.localdomain" as well as any hostname ending in ".localhost" or ".localhost.localdomain" are resolved to the IP addresses 127.0.0.1 and ::1.

So, this seems to explain that Linux OSes that have DNS resolution based on systemd will have this behaviour, and others (like Windows and MacOS) do not.

(So, this seemed a systemd question after all :-)

(This question is in fact a duplicate of https://serverfault.com/questions/1065513/how-does-linux-resolve-wildcard-locahost-subdomains-e-g-ping-test-localhost/1065514#1065514 - just using systemd-resolved instead of nss-myhostname , and if anyone knows how to link them both ways, could help others searching by other words).